# Auto incrementing field in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to implement an auto incrementing field in mongodb as highlighted in the docs (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/). However, I'm not exactly sure what is the best way to do so in mongoose.

I have a CounterSchema and a UserSchema, and I'm wondering where to put the getNextSequence function, and how to call it from the User Schema?

```
//counter.js
var CounterSchema = new Schema({
  category: String,
  seq: Number
});

//done in mongo shell
db.counters.insert({category: 'userIndex', seq: 0})

//user.js
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  UserIndex: Number
}

//per mongodb docs -> not sure where I should insert it
function getNextSequence(name) {
   var ret = db.counters.findAndModify(
          {
            query: { _id: name },
            update: { $inc: { seq: 1 } },
            new: true
          }
   );

   return ret.seq;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try pre save async middleware like this

```
User.pre('save', true, function(next, done){
  var self = this;
  var Autoincrement = mongoose.model('Autoincrement');
  if (self.isNew){ 
    Autoincrement.getNext(function(err, val){
      if (err) return done(err);
      self.auto = val;
      done();
    });
  }else{
   // done should be called after next
   setTimeout(done,0);
  }
  next();
});
```